# Django application: Gunicorn Procfile --max-requests configuration: Would the periodic workers-restart kill the tasks(process) running inside it?

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gunicorn

I have been facing memory leaks in my Django application and for some reason, I am not able to get rid of them. Here I wanted to try with Gunicorn --max-requests config to restart the gunicorn workers periodically to release the memory.

I had a few concerns here before taking it to production,

1. Would this periodic restart kill any process running inside it?
2. Or would it wait for the worker to be idle before restarting it?

I was assuming the basic philosophy will be wait it to be idle before restarting it. but I did not find documents backing this up. Any insights on this will be helpful.

Comment: how do you found memory leaks in you django application?

Comment: Add a datadog integration and monitor the sever instance memory spikes or inspect the gunicorn workers(process) after ssh into the server. there will be a gradual spike in the memory held by the gunicorn workers. you will see that the memory is not released back to os. there are many other work arounds to figure out using the python GC module or tracemalloc

ref: https://adamj.eu/tech/2019/09/19/working-around-memory-leaks-in-your-django-app

Comment: I am unsure if I am experiencing something you were afraid of when asking, "Would this periodic restart kill any process running inside it?"? I am using `gunicorn` with `gthread` workers. One request handler off-loads long-running task (data import) onto separate `threading.Thread`. I've tried to resolve increasing memory consumption with `--max-requests` but this caused the off-loaded task to be killed alongside the worker at times (so the data import is dropped half way through sometimes).